# Converting synonymous records in CSV file into MySQL DB entries

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have an application which populates a text file with information in CSV format. The problem is, the number of columns for each records should be flexible and it's not constant. I am trying to implement the same datastructure but in MySQL for faster reading and parallel writing from many nodes.

Here is a sample taken from my CSV File

```
like|love|adore|admire
hate|dislike
revive|resurrect
info|information|pieces of information|data
shoot|snipe|kill|hunt
```

Each record represents words with the same meaning. Later on, I get the synonyms of a word using that CSV file. For example, I get the synonyms for the word `hate` which is `dislike` using a function in my application that parses the csv file and outputs the matching words.

What options do I have to do the same implementation approach but using MySQL?

Comment: [SO post1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557134/good-database-and-structure-to-store-synonyms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with many-many relationships here. The off-the-top-of-my-head solution would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE words (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    word VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE synonyms (
    word_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    synonym_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (word_id, synonym_id)
);
```

Then, to get all the synonyms for word $X with an id of $Y:

```
SELECT w.id, w.word
FROM synonyms s
JOIN words w ON (s.synonym_id = w.id)
WHERE s.word_id = $Y;
```

This way you could also add antonyms at some point.

Comment: but notice that my approach was based on the fact that a synonym for synonym is a synonym as well. That's why I made the words with the same meaning to be on one line. Using your approach, How would I be able to add new synonyms for a word and its synonyms? In other words, If I have "a|b|c" that are synonyms to each other then I want to add word "d" as a synonym for "a", it should be added to b and c as well

Comment: Your program would have to do the select before you added a word to the list.  In other words, you say you want to add word d as a synonym for a.  You select the synonyms for a, which gives you b and c.  You then add the word d to the words table, and add the a|d row, the b|d row, and the c|d row to the synonyms table.